# Получить артикул товара WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно получить артикул текущего  товара на странице товара в WooCommerce и подставить его в инпут. По всему интернету не нашел как это делается.

Можно было бы, конечно, посмотреть как он сейчас выводится в карточке, но этого куска кода я тоже не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой файл `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php`

В нем такие строчки

```
<?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>

    <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>

<?php endif; ?>
```

В общем,

```
$sku = $product->get_sku();
```